# I want the player to match 5 items correctly before next scene button appears

Tags: java, scene

I currently have scenes where the player needs to move the correct object to the drop zone before the next scene button appears. I want a scene where the player needs to move all 5 objects to the correct drop zones before the next scene button appears, but I can't figure it out.

I don't know how to make a condition that all 5 objects need to be matched correctly first before the button for the next scene appears.

I use a tag on my object(player) and when matched, it activates the next scene button. So if I have 5 objects all using the same tag in the same scene, how do I delay the button from activating until all the objects are in their own drop zone. At the moment the button appears after the first object is matched.

TLDR: The Code below is for 1 object, how do I make it for 5 objects?

```java
public class TriggerButton : MonoBehaviour { 
    public GameObject Player;
    
    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other){
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)){
                 Player.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you use a variable to keep track of if objects are in their drop zone and each time an object has been taken to the drop zone by a player check if the other 4 are there too before activating the button. It could be a simple as keeping a count and incrementing it each time.

Comment: i actually figured out how to solve the issue. thank you for your relpy.

Comment: Why don't you add an answer to this question so you can help others in the future?

Comment: good idea, i will try to post it soon, need to make it simple.